# pass or listen data from BottomSheetDialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

Im trying to listen or pass data from an BotomSheetDialogFragment into Fragment to change something on the Fragment (Just like a picker).

I've tried with getTargetFragment to instantiate the listener but getting a compiler error Found: 'MyFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less..

Any ideas or i'm takin the wrong approach?

```
public class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {


ReportType reportType;

public interface OnChooseReasonListener {
    void onChooseReason(ReportType reportType);
}

OnChooseReasonListener listener;

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.picker_bottom_sheet_, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();

    //get null here!!!:
    listener = (OnChooseReasonListener)  getParentFragment();// or with getTargetFragment();
  }

  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.cool_button:
            this.reportType = ReportType.ME;
            //trying to execute the lisstener on null
            listener.onChooseReason(this.reportType);
            dismiss();
            break;
    }
}}
```

And the fragment:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment 
  implements View.OnClickListener, 
  MyBottomSheetDialogFragment.OnChooseReasonListener {
//....code here
  public void showPicker() {
        //getting and compiler error Wrong 1st argument type. 
        // picker. setTargetFragment(MyFragment.this , 300);
         picker.show(fm, picker.getTag());
     }
   @Override
    public void onChooseReason(ReportType reportType) {
        //not getting here
        Log(TAG, "You choose something" + reportType.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides that it's not working, that code smells a little since you're coupling `MyBottomSheetDialogFragment` with the object that created it.

The correct approach would be to have a method `void setOnChooseReasonListener(OnChooseReasonListener listener)` on `MyBottomSheetDialogFragment` and call it when you create the instance.

```
myBottomSheetDialogFragment.setOnChooseReasonListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks you are right. I need lots of experience and study to get better. And thank you to help me to see the answer. I miss also to post the code to instantiate the BottomSheet. Here is how i solved this from the fragment:

`public void showPicker() {
        MyBottomSheetDialogFragment bottomsheetPicker = new MyBottomSheetDialogFragment();
        bottomsheetPicker.setOnChooseReasonListener(this);
        bottomsheetPicker.show(fm, MyBottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
}`

Comment: @Xaren Can you please post the right code which worked? I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

***You can approach this by using the interface***

**First**
Create an interface class

```
interface CustomInterfaceClass {

    public void callbackMethod(String date);
}
```

**Second,**
Initialize the interface class in **Activity** or **fragment**
As I am using in the fragments class

```
 //interface for callback
    private CustomInterface callback;
```

**Third,** Make sure you have initialized the **callback** interface object within the **onCreateView** or **OnCreate** method.

> //if you facing an error while initializing such as **this** keyword
> not assigned to the callback method that means you didn't implement
> the interface fragmentAclass.

```
callback=this;
```

**Fourth,**
Don't forget to implement the override method within the FragmentAClass

```
@Override
    public void callbackMethod(String date) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Yes"+date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Fifth,**
Now move to **BottomSheetDialogFragment**  or **FragmentBclass**

> Add callback method constructor such as this

```
  private CustomInterface callback;

    public Disconnect_fragment( CustomInterface callback) {
        this.callback=callback;
    }
    public Disconnect_fragment( ) {

    }
```

**Lastly** Now you can pass the value by using this method and will receive in the **FragmentAclass**

```
callback.callbackMethod("your passing value");
```